# How can I change default date time format from English to Farsi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, umbraco, cultureinfo

I want to change showing date time format from English to Farsi in backed Umbraco.
I apply this setting in web.config.But did not work.
(date picker(publish at & Remove at) in properties tab)

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" uiCulture="fa" culture="fa"/>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: do you know any thing about globalization in Asp.net if you want more info let me now to create a post for you

Comment: I'm using Umbraco version 4.11.6

Comment: when do you want to change the Date time display format at design time or in run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language in the Umbraco backend is determined by the user logged in. As of right now, Umbraco only supports the following languages out of the box:

- Danish
- German
- English (UK)
- English (US)
- Spanish
- French
- Hebrew (Israel)
- Italian
- Japanese
- Korean
- Dutch
- Norwegian
- Polish
- Portuguese Brazil
- Russian
- Swedish
- Chinese (Simple)

Depending on which language is selected for that specific user, the date will display in the format appropriate to that culture.

This forum post, [Farsi and rtl support....](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/31872-Farsi-and-rtl-support), gives some information on how to add a new translation, if that interests you at all.

Answer (score 2):

The date format did not change based on used language for me.

I see date format hard-coded in umbraco_client\DateTimePicker\umbDateTimePicker.js
Change as desired then update client dependency:

1. App_Data\Temp\ClientDependency - either dump the CDJs or lookup which exact one is being used for umbDateTimePicker.js in the appropriate XML file for your server "{ServerName}-{IDString}-map.xml" and then remove the CDJ file that is the compiled js including umbDateTimePicker.js
2. Restart app / appPool to trigger the generation of the new ClientDependency file with your new settings.

I'm also seeing hard-coded date time format strings in umbraco.controls: umbraco.uicontrols.DatePicker.DateTimePicker.DateTime setter.

Done on Various Umbraco 4.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

As i search, unfortunately umbraco does not support `Persian` date time forma but you can study [FormatDateTime](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Reference/umbraco.library/FormatDateTime) and change the appearance to format like `yyyy/mm/dd` but for full name of months like `فروردین` `اردیبهشت` you should create your own control or use other staff like   [PersianDate® (PD)](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=2839)
In case of code to develop a custom control you can study [PersianCalendar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/%20system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx)
and this tiny solution :^)

if your date is a Gregorian date then First you must convert it to Jalali date like this:

```
    PersianCalendar jc = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime date = new DateTime(jc.GetYear(d), jc.GetMonth(d), jc.GetDayOfMonth(d));
    string print = string.Format("{0:0000}/{1:00}/{2:00}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
```

but if your date is a Jalali date already then just use:

```
    string print = string.Format("{0:0000}/{1:00}/{2:00}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
```

now if you have a string contains a Jalali date like "1390/12/10" and you want to get its day name it ll be a bit tricky.

```
    public static string GetDayOfWeekName(this DateTime date)
    {
        PersianCalendar jc = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime d = jc.ToDateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, PersianCalendar.PersianEra);

        switch (d.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday: return "شنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday: return "يکشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Monday: return "دوشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: return "سه‏ شنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: return "چهارشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday: return "پنجشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Friday: return "جمعه";
            default: return "";
        }
```

First you Should convert it to Gregorian Date then get the Day Name.
but not for Months name:

```
    public static string GetMonthName(this DateTime date)
    {
        switch (date.Month)
        {
            case 1: return "فررودين";
            case 2: return "ارديبهشت";
            case 3: return "خرداد";
            case 4: return "تير‏";
            case 5: return "مرداد";
            case 6: return "شهريور";
            case 7: return "مهر";
            case 8: return "آبان";
            case 9: return "آذر";
            case 10: return "دي";
            case 11: return "بهمن";
            case 12: return "اسفند";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
```

i would be appreciated if i could provide you more useful post and please let me know it!